# Passing the image to bootrap modal

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

im trying to create lightbox when image is click modal will show the original image with the actual size and at the same time it will have option to **next > picture** and **close** the modal how can i achieved this. im using laravel 6. my code below

**Blade:**

```
 <div class="row">
            @foreach($group->images as $key=> $img)
            <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-3" data-img-url="{{asset('storage/'.$img->photo)}}">
                <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$img->photo)}}" class="img-fluid image-control">

            </a>
           @endforeach
        </div>
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img class="" src="#"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
<script>
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
    $('#myModal img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-img-url')); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `li` use `div` instead:

```js
<script>
    $('div a').click(function(e) {
        $('#myModal img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-img-url')); 
    });
</script>
```